# XMPP - user search in iphone sdk ? use of XEP-0055 in iphone sdk?

Tags: ios4, xmpp, openfire

i am sending this IQ to openfire server

```
< iq type="set" from="admin@localhost.localdomain" to="localhost.localdomain" id="search2" xml:lang="en" > < query xmlns="jabber:iq:search" > < first > admin < /first > < /query > < /iq >
```

but getting following response from server,

```
< iq type="error" id="search2" from="localhost.localdomain" to="admin@localhost.localdomain/b91c09e5"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:search" >  < first > admin < /first > < /query > < error code="501" type="cancel" > < feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/ > < /error > < /iq >
```

even if i have installed search plugin and also enabled user search in openfire server...

Why this is happening ? How to solve this issue ? Any suggestion or help ?

i have also sent disco query to server to check which features are supported:

Input:

here what i get as output:

i didn't find anything related to user search on server in this list....!!

Comment: i have also pass this iq first, </p> <iq type='get'
    from='admin@localhost.localdomain'
    to='localhost.localdomain'
    id='search1'
 xml:lang='en'>
 <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'/>
 </iq>

Comment: but in this case also i have received error code: 501 , feature not implemented response from server.

Comment: here "localhost.localdomain" is server name.

Answer (score 0):

**urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas**

I think you need to handle "stanzas" from your client application.

Comment: I am already creating custom stanza from my client app. as per document XEP-0055, i am creating custom iq stanzas and passing them accrodingly....

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to send [XEP-55](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html) to another component.  Use [XEP-30](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html) (Disco) to search your local server for a component that implements the jabber:iq:search feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iq type='set' id='purple9ae3ed' to='vjud.yourserver.org'>
   <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
     <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='first'><value>Rub*</value></field>
    </x>
  </query>
</iq>
```