# XEP 0055 (Jabber search) with iphone SDK

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I am creating a XMPP sample on ios. What I am trying to do is search user over xmpp. I checked the opernfire server and it has the search plugin enabled. I gone through [XEP:0055](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html#schema) and found the stanza. I also gone through [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385151/xmpp-user-search-in-iphone-sdk-use-of-xep-0055-in-iphone-sdk) but did

I am done with xmpp connection and login. Now here are the details regarding to my server:

Host Name = 10.x.x.x;
Server name = abcd;

The request format I got from the XEP 0055 link is:

```
<iq type='set' from='romeo@montague.net/home' to='characters.shakespeare.lit' id='search2' xml:lang='en'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
        <last>Capulet</last>
    </query>
</iq>
```

I don't know what `characters.shakespeare.lit` is. I assume this is the server name. So I created following request:

```
<iq to="abcd" id="search2" xml:lang="en">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search">
       <Username>kapil</Username>
    </query>
</iq>
```

but I am not getting any response. I tried to replace the `to` value with following `search.abcd` and `10.x.x.x` but I am not even receiving any response IQ for this rquest.

Any help plz.

Answer (score 1):

shakespeare.lit is the xmpp host name. 'characters' is the Search service Name.

Answer (score 0):

It is the name of a directory service. If you connect to a server, you can retrieve the list of services and use that server's directory service. Alternatively, you can use any server's directory service (depending on the service's configuration, you do not have to be connected to the server hosting the service).

Comment: thanks for your reply but didn't understood you. What's wrong I am doing?

Comment: Just read section 1 and 2 of the XEP you quoted yourself, you can see that "to" refers to the directory service. Read XEP-0030 to find out more about services in the Jabber network.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var iq = $iq({
          type: 'set',
          id: 'search2',
          to: 'vjud.yourserver.org'
    })
.c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:search'})
.c('x', {xmlns: 'jabber:x:data', type:'submit'})
.c('field', {var: 'first'}).c('value','Rub*').up(); 
conn.sendIQ(iq);
```

note: **to: characters.shakespeare.lit**

**Not your server but the vcard service search.**